# How to track team affiliation' changes over the years in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R with 3 columns as follows :

```
user_id | team | year
001     |  A   | 2018
002     |  B   | 2018
003     |  C   | 2018
001     |  A   | 2019
002     |  C   | 2019
003     |  C   | 2019
004     |  B   | 2019
```

Note : year has values from 2018-2022.

Now, each user_id has its Team affiliation in a given year. That affiliation may change in the following year, or may simply not be present anymore.

I want to track that change in numbers:

**(1)** how many users were in 2018 for each team

**(2)** how many changed their team in 2019

**(3)** how many of them left

and **(4)** how many new users joined.

Similarly, for each of the following years.

I don't know where to begin or how to compute this. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, using `tidyverse`:

```
# (1) how many users were in each team in 2018
df %>%
  filter(year == 2018) %>%
  count(team)

# (2) how many changed their team in 2019
df <- df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(changed_team = team != lag(team)) 

df %>%
    filter(changed_team) %>%
    pull(changed_team) %>%
    sum()

# (3) how many of them left [each team in 2019?]
df %>%
    filter(!is.na(changed_team)) %>%
    group_by(year, team) %>%
    summarise(left = sum(changed_team))

# (4) how many new users joined [each team in any year?]
df %>%
    group_by(year, team) %>%
    count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(row=row_number(), max=max(row), .by=c(user_id, team)) %>% 
  mutate(row2=max(data.table::rleid(team)), .by=c(user_id)) %>% arrange(user_id,team)


# how many users were in 2018 for each team
df %>% filter(year==2018) %>% count(team)


# how many changed their team in 2019
df %>% filter(year==2019 & row2>1) %>% count()


# how many of them left
df %>% filter(year==2019 & max==1 & row2>1 & row==1) %>% count()


# how many new users joined
df %>% filter(max==1 & row2==1 & row==1) %>% count()
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind this? ->  ```df %>% mutate(row=row_number(), max=max(row), .by=c(user_id, team)) %>% 
  mutate(row2=max(data.table::rleid(team)), .by=c(user_id)) %>% arrange(user_id,team)
```

Comment: here I created the row_number per user_id and team, so it helps us to know how many users are there per team using the max function. Then identify how unique users are there per team using the rleid